# How to handle the query when the Select columns are more than the Insert?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to handle this scenario where the `funnel` table has fewer columns (or fewer columns that I want to insert) when I need to select more columns from `demoTable` ?

I get this: Column count doesn't match count row

```
INSERT INTO funnel 
            ( 
                        id, 
                        visitor, 
                        stage 
            ) 
select b_id, 
       visitor_name, 
       visitor_stage',
       visitor_page,
       visitor_time
from demoTable
```

Comment: Easy, simply select the same number of columns that you insert.

Comment: Review your database design to make sure it satisfies the business requirements.

Comment: @jarlh but I don't want to create empty columns just for that

Comment: Then SELECT fewer columns.

Comment: You must select only 2 columns if you are trying to insert only 2 columns! Assuming the `id` is autoincrement that does not count

Comment: You can `SELECT b_id, visitor_name, visitor_stage FROM demoTable` any reason you can't just do that?

Comment: Ask yourself why you want to copy data from one table to another. Usually you store data only once.

Answer (score 1):

You can't insert by selection with a mismatching number of fields. Select the fields from the source table that match the ones in the destination table and write the query accordingly:

```
INSERT INTO funnel (id, visitor, stage) 
SELECT b_id, visitor_name, visitor_stage FROM demoTable
```